# Represent a complex JSON object with a database schema

Tags: mysql, json, database

I'm trying to create a database from which I can obtain data to store in the following JSON object:

```
{
    "races": [
        {
            "name": "Mountain Dwarf",
            "asi": {
                "str": 2,
                "dex": 0,
                "con": 2,
                "int": 0,
                "wis": 0,
                "cha": 0
            },
            "proficiencies": {
                "languages": [ "Common", "Dwarvish" ],
                "armor": [ "light", "medium" ],
                "weapons": [ "battleaxe", "handaxe", "throwing hammer", "warhammer" ],
                "tools": {
                    "choose": 1,
                    "tools": [ "smith's tools", "brewer's supplies", "mason's tools" ]
                }
            },
            "darkvision": 60
        },
        {
            "name": "Wood Elf",
            "asi": {
                "str": 0,
                "dex": 2,
                "con": 0,
                "int": 0,
                "wis": 1,
                "cha": 0
            },
            // etc.
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm far more comfortable with storing data in JSON objects than in a database, so I'm trying to think backwards. **How would I be able to represent this "multi-layered" object as a SQL table?**

### My Best Guess

From the research that I've done, I think a good way of going about it is to set up several different tables and then join them to get all the information I need.

#### Example 1

For example, I might have a `race` table and a `race_asi` table with seven column names: `race_id`, `str`, `dex`, `con`, `int`, `wis`, and `cha`, with a row for each race.

#### Example 2

I might also have a `weapons` table and a `race_proficiency_weapons` table, where the latter is a join table between the `races` and `weapons` tables, so it has two columns: `race_id` and `weapon_id`.

I considered just having one `race_proficiency_weapons` table with a `race_id` column and a column for each type of weapon, where the data is just a boolean that indicates whether or not the race has that type of proficiency, but I want users of the program I'm writing to be able to add additional weapon types on the fly (unlike the ASIs mentioned in example 1).

---

Is this an appropriate solution to storing this data? Again, I'm a bit of an SQL noob so are there any issues with this solution that I'm not seeing? If so, what would be an appropriate solution?